# Using apply with lambda

Tags: apply

It seems like for a function with no arguments, `apply` and `funcall` should have the same behavior.  However,

```
(let ((x (lambda nil (message "called"))))
  (message "x: %s" x)
  (funcall x)
  (apply x))
```

produces this output in `*Messages*`

```
x: (closure (t) nil (message called))
called
apply: Symbol’s function definition is void: closure
```

I get a similar result if I pass the `lambda` as an argument to a method, which (I think) gives me dynamic binding instead of lexical binding.

The documentation for `lambda` says (in part)

> Regardless, the result is a
> function, i.e., it may be stored as the function value of a
> symbol, passed to ‘funcall’ or ‘mapcar’, etc.

So `apply` is not explicitly included there, but it seems like it should be part of `etc.`

Is there some reason why `apply` does not work here that I am missing?

For my current case, I can use `funcall`, but I would like to better understand what is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding of how to use the `apply` function.
Please read the documentation carefully:

> Call FUNCTION with our remaining args, **using our last arg as list of args**.

So it should be

```lisp
(apply x ())
```

instead of

```lisp
(apply x)
```